# PHP MySQL - How can I sort paginated results by a calculated field?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, calculated-field

For context, though the scope is not limited to this, I'm using CakePHP 2.4.4 with it's pagination function. This queries for results (with ORDER, LIMIT and OFFSET, I believe), and once the results are returned, I calculate a field. In this case, the user enters a Postcode, and upon results being returned, the geographical distance between the search postcode and the result postcodes are individually calculated. I can't order by this, as I only have one page of results at a time.

How would I do this manually? I imagine I could get all results in a query, then calc distance for each result, then order, then drop those not on that page, but that seems very expensive. Autotrader, for example, return hundreds of thousands of results, and they can be ordered by distance, calculated there and then.

The maths is done in PHP on my project, but I expect this needs to be moved to within a query, but I think that makes it expensive.

How can I order all results by a calculated field not actually stored in the database?

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: added, thanks, but in this case it is only for context, I think the solution would have a broader scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure PHP here is the right place to do the math. Especially if there is a lot of records to filter in that table.

You might want to look at 
http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/06/12/geocoding-with-cakephp/

You seem to be working with distances.
In that article the whole calculation is done in the SQL directly - using virtual fields and a clean approach via behavior.
Try to get this working. It will make it not only easy for you to work with distances or lat/lng fields, it will also keep it DRY.

Sorting and filtering is all included.

Comment: Looking at CakePHP 3's details, I thought it best not to begin relying on virtual fields as they're being dropped? But I will take a look, thanks!

Comment: They are migrated into the model layer into a more native solution. So they still exist, just not under this name, but a better build-in solution.

Comment: Ah, good news, so a virtual field would be a good solution. However, although in my project the calculated field is postcode, for further use I'd need to be able to use my own function for a virtual field - do you know how to do this manually, rather than with that plugin?

Comment: You need to be more specific. I, for example, have a table "postal_codes" that contains all data including a lt/lng for each postal code. I use that lat/lng geo info to build the query conditions via the behaviors virtual field.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do - but without the plugin. That way I can do it again for other calculated data in future where there isn't a plugin. I think I need to make a virtual field on the fly in beforeFind

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing complex calculation move the code to a store procedure.

Comment: As in DB Stored Procedure, or PHP stored procedure? Either way, this doesn't really answer the question of how to do this

Comment: i was not away that php has stored procedures

Comment: *not the same thing - can do the same job